# How is it true that $\vert e^{iw(r)} - 1 \vert \leq \min\{\vert w(r) \vert, 2\}$?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

I'm reading a [thesis](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/83693) where the author uses this inequality (page 33) to prove a lemma:

[image]

I know $\vert e^{iw(r)} - 1 \vert = \sqrt{2-2\cos(w(r))}$, which is at least $0$ and at most $2$, but how can I conclude that $\vert e^{iw(r)} - 1 \vert \leq \min\{\vert w(r) \vert, 2\}$? I've included the link to the thesis in case there is context missing. I've been stuck with this for a while now.

Comment: It is a mean value theorem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208609/mean-value-theorem-for-complex-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture. $|e^{iw}-1|$ is a length of side $[e^{iw}e^{i0}]$ of a triangle $\Delta e^{iw} e^{i0} o$ and $w$ is length of arc. If $w>2$, then $|e^{iw}-1| \leq 2$.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.