# Complex analysis, normal families

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to determine whether or not the following families of functions in $H(\mathbb{D})$ are normal or not.

The first family is

$$\mathcal{F}=\left\{f\in H(\mathbb{D}); f(0)=0,\ \sup_{z\in\mathbb{D}}\ |f''(z)|\cdot(1-|z|^2)<+\infty\right\}$$

The second family is

$$\mathcal{G}=\left\{ g\in H(\mathbb{D}); \sup_{z\in\mathbb{D}}\left|g(z)-\dfrac{z^3}{(1-z^2)} \right|<+\infty\right\}$$

I imagine the idea is trying to prove these are locally uniformly bounded in $\mathbb{D}$ and then apply Montel's theorem, but I can't make heads or tails of how to bound these. Also, I'm supposed to provide additional conditions for normality in case these families aren't normal. Any hints?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First family:

Let $\mathcal{F}_1\subset \mathcal{F}$ be the family of linear functions such that $f(0)=0$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_1=\{az; a\in \mathbb{C}\}$. This family is not normal, as it is not locally uniformly bounded ($\underset{ n\in \mathbb{N}}{\forall}\underset{z\in \mathbb{D}-\{0\}}{\forall} \exists f\in \mathcal{F}:|f(z)|=n$, namely $f(w):=\frac{n}{z}w$), and so neither is $\mathcal{F}$.
However, if one imposes the condition $|f'(0)|<k$ and a stricter condition like $\sup_{\mathbb{D}}|f''(z)|(1-|z|^2)<h$ the result follows. In fact, given a compact set $\Gamma \subset \mathbb{D}$ of diameter $\rho<1$, we have
 $$|f'(z)|\le |f'(0)|+\sup_{\Gamma}|f''(z)||z|\le |f'(0)|+|z|\frac{h}{1-\rho^2}\le k+\frac{\rho h}{1-\rho^2}\\
|f(z)|\le |f(0)|+\sup_{\Gamma}|f'(z)||z|\le \left(k+\frac{\rho h}{1-\rho^2}\right)|z|\le \left(k+\frac{\rho h}{1-\rho^2}\right)\rho$$

- Second family

Note that $\mathcal{G}$ contains the family $\mathcal{G}_1:=\left\{f(z)=a+\frac{z^3}{1-z^2}; a\in \mathbb{C}\right\}$, which is not locally bounded (as it is not bounded in $0$). However, one condition which is sufficient to ensure normality is to modify the definition of $\mathcal{G}$ as follows:

$$\mathcal{G}=\left\{f\in H(\mathbb{D});\sup_{z\in \mathbb{D}}\left|f(z)-\frac{z^3}{1-z^2}\right|<k\right\}$$

The normality of these redefined $\mathcal{G}$ follows from the fact that, given a compact set $\Gamma\subset \mathbb{D}$ of diameter $\rho<1$, we have

$$|f(z)|\le \left|\frac{z^3}{1-z^2}\right|+k\le \frac{\rho^3}{1-\rho^2}+k$$

Comment: Damn, that was a quick response, thanks a lot @Caffeine
I often have a hard time finding counterexamples and such, but I'm definitely taking notes on your approach and will study it carefully so I can come up with similar strategies. Appreciate it :)

Comment: Hi again @Caffeine, I'm trying to work out the inequality for $\left| f'(z)\right|$ but I don't quite follow. I'm under the assumption the Taylor series is involved, but I don't understand where did the rest of the terms of the series go, and why are we taking sup for the second derivative instead of using the usual $f''(0)$ that would come up. I tried using Cauchy''s inequality for the n-th derivative but I get a divergent series :/
Thanks

Comment: @Surek there is no need to do this. The result I used is called the mean value inequality, and can be derived as follows: let $\gamma_z$ be the straight line joining $0$ and $z$. We then have $f(z)=f(0)+\int_{\gamma_z}f'(t)dt$, and thus (by triangle inequality and the fact that $|\int f|\le \int |f|$) we get $|f(z)|\le |f(0)|+\int |f'|$, and if the derivative is bounded by $M$ $|f(z)|\le |f(0)|+M|z|$. I used this inequality twice: first to derive a bound for $f'$ (since its derivative, $f''$, is bounded we can apply the inequality) and then, once obtained the bound for $f'$, for $f$

Comment: This result (which can be easily extended to vector valued functions of a real variable) is true provided the domain is convex (as otherwise we cannot link two points by a straight line), but there is a slight generalization that still holds, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208609/mean-value-theorem-for-complex-functions .

Comment: Ok I will look into that, thank you very much :)